# Merge multiple tables by comparing multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I have multiple three column tables that share two rows in common:

```
DailyCosts:                          DailyPrices
CodeRole CodeRegion DailyCost        CodeRole CodeRegion DailyPrice
1        1          123              1        1          155
1        2          120              1        2          148
2        1          100              2        1          110

AnnualCosts:
CodeRole CodeRegion AnnualCost       CodeRole CodeRegion AnnualPrice
1        1          1023             1        1          1055
1        2           920             1        2           948
2        1          1100             2        1          1110
```

I want to combine all for tables into one:

```
CostsPrices:
CodeRole CodeRegion DailyCost DailyPrice AnnualCost AnnualPrice
1        1          123       155        1023       1055
1        2          120       148         920        948
2        1          100       110        1100       1110
```

If I had only one matching criterion (ie just `codeRole`) I could use a vlookup, but I am at a loss as to how to do this with multiple criteria.

Comment: those tables in the same sheet ?

Comment: Currently they are each on separate sheets, but I can place them on the same one if it makes a difference, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate (even if only temporarily) the key fields and use that.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I've manage to do it by multiplying boolean values `=(AnnualPricesC!$A$2:$A$20153=CostsPrices!$A2)*(AnnualPricesC!$B$2:$B$20153=CostsPrices!$B2)*(AnnualPricesC!$C$2:$C$20153)`, but this seams colse enough, thanks

Comment: You answer is atleast as valid as the way I resolved the problem, if not more. And I'd rather accept your answer so you get the reputation bonus for taking the time to answer. (Thanks btw)